# psql: FATAL: invalid value for parameter "client_encoding": "WIN1252"

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift, psql

I am using psql with Redshift.  Unfortunately, Redshift is uses PostgreSQL 8.0.2.
So when I downloaded the latest version of PostgreSQL (9.6.1) and try logging into a database, I get the error:

```
cannot connect from psql due to invalid parameter "client_encoding"
```

Instructions here https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=529120 suggest

```
set PGCLIENTENCODING=UTF8
```

But when I open SQL Shell (psql) in Windows, I am never given the chance to enter this command:

[image]

How can I bridge this gap/fix this error?  Thanks

Comment: Where is there a CTE used in the above code?

Comment: Oops wrong question. sorry. *deleted*

Answer (score 1):

`set x=y` is the Windows CMD syntax to set an **environment variable**, just as `x=y;export x` or `export x=y` or `setenv x y` is on most Unix shells.

You can pre-set a (semi)permanent env var in Windows from ControlPanel / System (or ThisPC rightclick Properties), AdvancedSystemSettings, Advanced tab, EnvironmentVariables button. Or from CMD with the `SETX` command; `SETX /?` for help or http://ss64.com/nt/setx.html . (Or directly in the registry, but if you have enough skill to use regedit safely you wouldn't ask this Q.)

Answer (score 0):

this link provides some info too.

Just run this command in the command line: `SET PGCLIENTENCODING=utf-8`

[image]

https://dwgeek.com/psql-invalid-value-for-parameter-client_encoding-redshift.html/